Post to Facebook group using graph-api
I implemented an android application and i am the administrator of a facebook group, i want to let my app's users post in my group using graph-api.
I created a business app in facebook developer console
I used Graph API Explorer with v21.0 to post in the group using this endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v21.0/group/feed#publish

In the requirements section, it's mentioned that publish_to_groups permission is required but with Graph API Explorer i can't find it in the list.
I tried with other permission: pages_show_list, pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts. But when i run  this error is thrown:
(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \ either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \ and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \ requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \ sufficient administrative permission

how can i achieve this requirement ?
update:
Even when using a "Consumer"type app, the publish_to_groups permission is not listed.

"but with Graph API Explorer i can't find it in the list" - that is probably due to the chosen app type. It should rather be "Consumer" than "Business."

@C3roe Even when using a "Consumer"type app, the publish_to_groups permission is not listed.

And what happens when you ask for the permission via your android app, instead of trying to create the token in GAE?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
